# Update to > Angular 7 - string-typed router loadChildren still working

Tags: angular

I have recently updated an application from Angular version 7 to 8. I was under the impression that my string typed `loadChildren` in my `app-routing-module` would be deprecated and I would need to convert to functions.

For example, this conversion:

```
path: 'admin-users',
loadChildren: './modules/user/user.module#UserModule',


path: 'admin-users',
loadChildren: () => import('./modules/user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule)
```

However my routes as they exist seem to be behaving properly. Am I wrong in thinking they needed updated?

Answer (score 1):

In the [upgrade site](https://update.angular.io/?v=6.0-8.0), it says its removed in V9, so I guess that's why it works

[image]

[image]

Comment: @noclist does this answer your question, can it be closed?